# where can i use the uploadStoredFiles function in the code

Tags: fine-uploader

where can i use the uploadStoredFiles function in the code in case i used autoUpload to false in fineuploader Plugin

```
       <script>
        var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                    debug: true,
                    element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
                    request: {
                        endpoint: "endpoint.php"
                    },
                    chunking: {
                    enabled: true,
                    concurrent: {
                        enabled: true
                },
                success: {
                    endpoint: "endpoint.php?done"
                }
            },

           autoUpload:false,
      });

        </script>

<button onchange="myFunction();">Done?</button>
<script>
function myFunction(){
    uploadStoredFiles();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call uploadStoredFiles anywhere and anytime you want to, whenever you want to trigger and upload all submitted files.

Comment: `uploadStoredFiles` isn't available on the global scope. You need to call the method on the Fine Uploader instance you created.